How to prove the existence of global attractors?
In conclusion, based on compactness and continuity of the semigroup, there are some methods to prove the existence of global attractors for the autonomous systems. In detail, there are five methods to prove it in terms of compactness of the associated semigroup.
(1) Uniformly compact semigroup method;
(2) Asymptotically compact semigroup method (semigroup decomposition method, γ-contraction semigroup, energy equation method);
(3) Asymptotically smooth semigroup method;
(4) ω-limit compact method (set-contraction method, uniform condition-(C));
(5) Weakly compact semigroup method.
There are two methods to prove the existence of global attractors in terms of continuity of the associated semigroup:
(1) Norm-to-weak continuous semigroup method;
(2) Closed operator semigroup method.
Reference: Qin Y, Su K. Attractors for Nonlinear Autonomous Dynamical Systems[M]. Les Ulis: EDP Sciences, 2022.
Are there other methods to prove it in terms of compactness of the associated semigroup?

The table of contents here may prove fruitful https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-4581-4
